# How to use Typekit/Adobe fonts with next/font in next 13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next.js13

I'm working in a project with a UI/UX designer, I'm coding his portfólio, for this, I'm using Next (13.4.7) with the app folder, but in the original project in the figma, the designer used the Gelica font, a font of Adobe Fonts. I was thinking that is easy to implement, because the google fonts are super easy, but I'm spending hours trying to use the font in the project.

I need to use the font somehow without use the pages folder, because it will need to do a lot of changes in the project, and I dont have much time do do this. I tried to use local fonts, but there's no way to download the font of Adobe Fonts, and I need to let all in the git repository, because I'm using vercel to deploy the website. What should I do?